# C# .Net 6 - HttpOnly Cookie with SameSite lax value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, samesite

I have this issue:
This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie header was blocked because it had the "SameSite=Lax" attribute but came from a cross-site response which was not the response to a top-level navigation. This response is considered cross-set because the URL has a different scheme than the current site.

If i use post request, it is work with samesite = lax, bit if i use get request i get 404 Forbidden error. How can i solve to work samesite lax with get requests?

i have this method what generate the Cookie:

```
private CookieOptions GetCookieOptions()
    {
        string domain = Request.Host.Host;
        var result = new CookieOptions
        {
            Secure = true,
            HttpOnly = true,
            IsEssential = true,
            Domain = domain,
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax
        };

        return result;
    }
```

and Here i add the cookie:

```
public async Task SetTokenAsync(HttpAccessToken tokenDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string serializedToken = await Task.FromResult(JsonSerializer.Serialize(tokenDto));
        string base64Token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedToken));
        CookieOptions cookieOptions = GetCookieOptions();
        cookieOptions.Expires = tokenDto.Deadline;
        Response.Cookies.Append(CookieKey, base64Token, cookieOptions);
    }
```

If i use SameSiteMode.None it is work, but with Lax it is not, and only just the GET requests made error.. Why? How can i solve this?
I read something and a possible solution is use POST request instead of GET, but i wouldn't like to change my all requests.

Change GET to POST, it is work but it is not a nice solution.

Comment: According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/samesite-cookie-update#samesite-cookie-attribute-2020-release), there are only Lax/Strict/None cookie types, so you can choose one based on your requirement.